# Convert std::string to std::time_t using only C++98

Tags: c++, string, datetime, c++98

My main problem is to compare current time (`const std::time_t now = std::time(NULL);`) with the given time (e.g., *"2017-12-14"*) which is std::string object. So, I am using `std::difftime(end, start)` function. But the problem is that at first I have to convert `std::string` to `std::time_t` object.

Is it possible convert it (format is *'yyyy-mm-dd'*) to `std::time_t` object using already known functions (using only **C++98**)?

I found a function `strptime` here: https://linux.die.net/man/7/feature_test_macros, but this is POSIX function. I need multi-platform code.

Also I think that it is a bad solution to gain '*yyyy*', '*mm*', 'dd' strings, convert those to `int` and assign to `std::tm`'s `tm_year`, `tm_mon`, `tm_mday` members correspondingly. (then convert `std::tm` to `std::time_t`)

Comment: Have you tried [`std::strftime`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/strftime)? It'll give you a string that you can compare to given time.

Comment: Avoiding to get 'yyyy', 'mm' etc is something one may agree upon but the net result is taking into account also the time format (yyyy/mm/dd or mm/dd/yyyy or what else?). So you get another variable in the mix, which may broaden your scope instead of focusing on a solution

Comment: @jrok As you mentioned `std::strftime` will give me a string which I will have to compare to `yyyy-mm-dd` string, but I need to compare std::time_t objects and not strings, because what if I'll have `yyyy:mm:dd` format instead of `yyyy-mm-dd`? In this case strings will be compared successfully and I can get wrong result. In case of comparing std::time_t objects, if wrong format have come, exception will be thrown from one of the functions which will be caught in above layers.

Comment: I pulled out K&R, looked at time.h, and the best option I saw there was fill out struct tm and call mktime. You don't like that? If <chrono> isn't avail, you want portability, and you are stuck with time_t, then I try to go back to time.h (and don't use their std:: names, use their time.h names from the C header).

Comment: I think you're down to "roll your own".  Here are handy formulas for doing that: http://howardhinnant.github.io/date_algorithms.html